# error when plotting means with geom_point for numeric x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a subset of my reproduced dataframe for use here. I am trying to plot the points and then the means of the points for a numeric, non-factor, x-axis.

```
structure(list(SITE_ID = c("AZ1", "AZ2", 
"AZ3", "AZ4", "AZ5", 
"AZ6", "AZ7", "AZ8", 
"AZ9", "AZ10", "KS1", "KS2", 
"KS3", "KS4", "KS5", "KS6", "KS7", "KS8", "KS9", "KS10", "KS11", 
"NMEX4", "NMEX3", "NMEX2", 
"NMEX1"), DATASET = c("AZ_B", "AZ_B", 
"AZ_B", "AZ_B", "AZ_B", "AZ_B", "AZ_B", "AZ_B", 
"AZ_B", "AZ_B", "KS_B", "KS_B", "KS_B", "KS_B", 
"KS_B", "KS_B", "KS_B", "KS_B", "KS_B", "KS_B", 
"KS_B", "NM_B", "NM_B", "NM_B", "NM_B"), num_temp_reps = c(7L, 
7L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 13L), stdv = c(0.0834575651234484, 
0.0611317465539431, 0.0965091506381606, 0.0805498856928655, 0.114537557812694, 
0.116984871610183, 0.0843571657410382, 0.0917016831235985, 0.106580906285764, 
0.0820200212513281, 0.0671432513890294, 0.034230833394556, 0.0660673914191362, 
0.0975109600124084, 0.0278177652794605, 0.162136833740925, 0.144981840255872, 
0.0529289869310672, 0.0555414059402315, 0.0722218413310142, 0.0654033698276827, 
0.0714675814159411, 0.0387847054136062, 0.13519289227636, 0.0379318889746079
)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 110L, 
111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 65L, 
66L, 67L, 68L), class = "data.frame")
```

this throws an error

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(ggpmisc)

df_means <- df %>% 
  group_by(DATASET,num_temp_reps) %>% 
  summarise(mean_stdv=mean(stdv))

ggplot(data=df, 
       aes(x=round(num_temp_reps), 
           y=stdv)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_point(data=df_means,col="red") +
  geom_smooth(method="lm",se=F) + 
  stat_fit_glance(method = "lm",
                  method.args = list(formula = (y) ~ (x)),
                  aes(label = sprintf('R^2~"="~%.3f~~italic(p)~"="~%.2f',
                                      stat(r.squared), stat(p.value))),
                  parse = TRUE) +
  scale_color_viridis_d() + facet_wrap(~DATASET,scales="free_x")

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'stdv' not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ggplot(data=df, 
       aes(x=round(num_temp_reps), 
           y=stdv)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_point(data=df_means,aes(x=round(num_temp_reps), 
                               y=mean_stdv),col="red") +
  geom_smooth(method="lm",se=F) + 
  stat_fit_glance(method = "lm",
                  method.args = list(formula = (y) ~ (x)),
                  aes(label = sprintf('R^2~"="~%.3f~~italic(p)~"="~%.2f',
                                      stat(r.squared), stat(p.value))),
                  parse = TRUE) +
  scale_color_viridis_d() + facet_wrap(~DATASET,scales="free_x")
```

And fixed it here. I had to add the specific column info for the means df. At first, I thought the error was because the group I used to summarize the y-axis values was numeric instead of a factor. However, that was not true!